# NFC Write and read tags between Android & iOs

Tags: ionic-framework, nfc, phonegap

Need to have some information about NFC reading and writing tags, with phonegap in IONIC

I would like to make an app with shared data between 2 mobiles, I want to know if it's possible to read and write it between two phones using a different OS like Android and iOs.

Do you know if it's possible or if it will have any limitation with this use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having a real NFC Card to acts as intermediary between devices, due to lacking NFC support in iOS
iOS <=> iOS is impossible
iOS <=> Android is complicated
Android <=> Android is complicated

iOS does not support NFC Peer to Peer, Android does support NFC Peer to Peer before Android 10 but it is now deprecated.

This leaves Host Card Emulation where one device pretends to be a real card, iOS does not support this (Only Apple themselves can do this), Android Supports this but it is not the simplest thing to do natively and probably does not have a module to help.

Better to use Bluetooth or Wifi Direct.